# How can I make an OR condition in RegExp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here is my code:

```
new RegExp((", eric\\b")||("eric\\b"), "g");
```

but there is something wrong in that code that it only reads the first condition.

It only outputs like this:

```
/, eric\b/g
```

I want it to output an OR condtion

Comment: `/(, eric\b)|(eric\b)/g` or better yet, `/,? ?eric\b/g`

Comment: you don't need to, and in fact should not, use the constructor form instead of the literal, unless you have dynamic values to be injected at run-time. as is, you need to feed RexExp one long quoted string, you're doing binary math between two string literals, resulting in RegExp being passed `0`

Comment: I indeed have dynamic values instead of eric. like this `(", "+tagValue+"\\b")`

Comment: `RegExp(',? ?'+strName+'\\b', g)` your way, working:  `RegExp("(, eric\\b)|(eric\\b)", "g")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables with the RegEx constructor and make the first `,` optional:

```
 new RegExp("(?:, )?" + name + "\\b"), "g");
```

Here is [an example](https://regex101.com/r/nI3pN5/1).

Comment: do note that non-capturing only works a few of the contexts in which RegExps are available in JS... also, you don't need "new " on the built-in JS Constructors (same for Array, Function, Object, but String and Date are justifiably different)